Issue of moisture release through fictional airtight carbon filament suit which allows for molecular oxygen exchange
My lead wears a suit made of a fictional material which allows the free exchange of oxygen on a molecular level, but is otherwise air tight. They exist in a toxic atmosphere that would kill them if exposed. My first and largest issue I see with this suit is perspiration. Our skin isn’t meant to be damp and if there’s no way to release the moisture, after a little sweat and a few hours, I feel my lead would begin to sustain erosion to the skin simply from the trapped moisture. Is there a more realistic way to propose the mechanics of this suit that will be more believable?

Check Dune's "stillsuits", they've got that thing covered pretty nicely.

Overheating will probably become an issue long before skin damage does. You need something to either absorb or get rid of excess moisture. What is adequate largely depends on the amount of physical activity the person is expected inside the suit and ambient temperatures, can you expand on that?

The weave of your suit will allow molecular oxygen to pass but not molecular water? The two hydrogen and an oxy vs. two oxy. They're about the same size. Why not adjust the weave to permit the water molecule? Most (if not all) toxic molecules are larger and wouldn't pass - and it solves the overheating problem. Unfortunately, that leaves the salt on the body and if you think the moisture is a problem... high concentrations of salt is much, much worse. A loose enough weave to allow emulsified salt to also pass would start to let toxic molecules through. That leaves you @Vesper's comment.

Your assumption regarding how quickly skin would start to "erode" is contradicted by the experience of people wearing wetsuits, drysuits and latex garments.  However, the immediate problem is not the moisture but the carbon dioxide - if exhaled CO2 can't get out then the pressure inside the suit will increase until no more O2 can get in.  There's also the issue of eating and excretion/defecation - how long does the person need to be in the suit continuously before a break in a "shirtsleeves" environment?
